# Inserir varios dados no ibexpert

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird

Bom galera a pouco tempo comecei a usar o firebird e estou com o seguinte problema , ao tentar inserir alguns dados diretamente no `IB Expert` ele me retorna os seguinte erro :

> Invalid token. Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -104. Token unknown
>   - line 4, column 1. (.

estou tentando inserir do seguinte modo :

```
INSERT INTO CIDADE (CODIGO,NOME,ESTADO) VALUES

(1, 'Afonso Cláudio', 8);
(2, 'Água Doce do Norte', 8);
(3, 'Águia Branca', 8);
(4, 'Alegre', 8);
(5, 'Alfredo Chaves', 8);
(6, 'Alto Rio Novo', 8);
(7, 'Anchieta', 8);
(8, 'Apiacá', 8);
(9, 'Aracruz', 8);
(10, 'Atilio Vivacqua', 8); ...
```

fica meio que fora de mão inserir um dado de cada vez porque são mais de 5.000 cidades, quando eu tento inserir apenas um dado de cada vez da certo .

Comment: Não seria uma `,` no lugar do `;` se não você precisa repetir o cabeçalho(`insert .... `)

Comment: Você precisa fazer um INSERT pra cada registro. Como são muitos, faça um script que gere isso pra você. Certamente, você tem os dados de cidade em algum lugar (um arquivo texto, por exemplo). Faça um script que percorra esse arquivo e produza outro arquivo com os INSERTs pra cada cidade.

Comment: @rray Já tentei de ambos os modos mas sempre me retorna o erro na segunda linha

Comment: @cantoni mesmo com vários cabeçalhos insert me volta o mesmo erro

Comment: @MatheusGoes, vc disse que um de cada vez dá certo, então deve ser algum tipo de separador que você precisa usar entre um INSERT e outro. Não me lembro de FB o suficiente pra te falar exatamente qual é esse separador, mas certamente ele existe.

Comment: Qual versão do fb está usando? tentou o `EXECUTE BLOCK `?

Comment: como eu falei sou novo no firebid então provavelmente eu não tentei o EXECUTE BLOCK , mas vou pesquisar para ve se pode ser por isso

Comment: Minha Versão do Firebird 2.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [documentação](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq336/) do firebird sugere, utilizar `EXECUTE BLOCK` para realizar multiplos inserts.

```
set term ^ ;
EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES (2, 'two');
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES (4, 'four');
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES (5, 'five');
END^
```

Para adicionar o cabeçalho a cada linha, utilize um editor de texto com suporte a regex como o notepad++, aperter ctrl + H

Primeiro marque a opção `regular expression`, em `find` digite `^`(inicio de linha) e no `replace` coloque o `INSERT INTO CIDADE (CODIGO,NOME,ESTADO) VALUES`, no começo de cada linha essa strings será adicionada.

Comment: Obg, consegui resolve